# Top bar menus not showing on mobile

Tags: menus, mobile

I am using the Bam theme in wordpress. There is a Top Bar where I have added some menus. It's showing on desktop but not on mobile or tablet. How can I resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Rabi

Comment: Welcome to wpse! thats not enogh information to go by, I would start with reading the theme documentation about how the theme works, you could contact the theme author for help about this. As it stands, without knowledge about that particular theme your question could not be answered.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you please check my site? Here's the link - https://www.filmomaniac.com/